# ProGuard obfuscation, java, Google Gson and generic collections - how to keep members?

Tags: java, generics, obfuscation, gson, proguard

I have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Queue<MyOtherClass> myQueue;
}
```

My problem is that I cannot get ProGuard to keep myQueue after serialization to json using Google Gson. What happens is that the member name "myQueue" is serialized as "a". Obviously, deserialization then breaks.

Here are some of the ProGuard configs I have tried.

```
-keepclassmembers class com.my.package.MyClass {
    #private java.util.Queue<com.my.package.MyOtherClass> myQueue;
    #private java.util.Queue<com.my.package.*> myQueue;
    private java.* myQueue;
}
```

With

```
private java.util.Queue<com.my.package.MyOtherClass> myQueue;
```

...ProGuard complained that the class was unknown. The message is:

> Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class `java.util.Queue<com.my.Package.MyOtherClass>'`

Using

```
private java.* myQueue;
```

....gets rid of the ProGuard warning, but, as I said, the member myQueue is not kept in the json output. It is serialized as "a".

The rest of the relevant ProGuard config is as follows:

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keepattributes *Annotation*
#gson
-keepattributes Signature
-adaptresourcefilenames    **.properties,**.gif,**.jpg,**.png,**.wav
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.properties,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
-optimizationpasses 3
-overloadaggressively
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification

-keep public class com.my.package.MyOtherClass {
}

-keepclassmembers class com.my.package.MyOtherClass {
    [a large number of private members are listed]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since java class files contain erased generics, ProGuard expects erased types too. So `java.util.Queue<com.my.Package.MyOtherClass>` should be specified as `java.util.Queue`.

The alternative with a wildcard works if you specify `java.**` (with double ** to match classes in subpackages too).

Cfr. the [ProGuard manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html)

Comment: Thank you. I'm struggling with the manual. I have not figured out what is required in order to have the serialized member names I expect. In most cases I need the exact member name to be serialized. This is my current problem. However, in a few cases, I have used @SerializedName("betterName") protected String poorName; And I have yet to get to the point where I can see if @SerializedName is working...