# How to not obfuscate a method with list argument

Tags: java, android, proguard

I have a class that looks like this:

```
package com.hi

class A {
    void doSomething(java.util.List<SomeClass> list) {
    }
}
```

Then in my proguard.cfg I tried this:

```
-keep class com.hi.A {
    void doSomething(java.util.List<com.hi.SomeClass>);
}
```

But that fails proguard with:

```
[proguard] Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'java.util.List<com.hi.SomeClass>'
```

I couldn't find anywhere in the proguard docs about using template arguments.  Has anyone been able to keep this kind of method?

Comment: Consider looking for "generics" instead of "templates" -- [This related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924425/how-do-you-stop-proguard-from-removing-type-parameters) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794220/proguard-obfuscation-java-google-gson-and-generic-collections-how-to-keep-me) might help.

Comment: The second link you provided gave me the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
-keep class com.hi.A {
    void doSomething(java.util.List);
}
```